# Pandas how to turn column of lists into multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large DataFrame where one column (COL) includes a range (i.e. list) of values. I want to turn this COL into individual columns labeled with the specific number and containing a 1 if the specific number is in COL else 0.

Below is my current approach. However, this is slow with high number of OBSERVATIONS and MAX_VALUE.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

OBSERVATIONS = 100000 # number of values 600000
MAX_VALUE = 400 # 400

_ = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':np.random.randint(2,20,OBSERVATIONS),
    'b':np.random.randint(30,MAX_VALUE,OBSERVATIONS)
})


_['res'] = _.apply(lambda x: range(x['a'],x['b']),axis=1)

for i in range(MAX_VALUE):
    _[f'{i}'] = _['res'].apply(lambda x: 1 if i in x else 0)
```

Comment: if your data is in `df` then do `pd.DataFrame(df['res'].values.tolist())`

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the list in `'res'` is a range with an increment of 1?

Comment: @JayMody yes it is, random start and random end though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and do the calculations in `numpy` and then insert the `numpy` array to the dataframe. This is about 5 times faster:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

OBSERVATIONS = 100_000 # number of values 600000
MAX_VALUE = 400 # 400

_ = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':np.random.randint(2,20,OBSERVATIONS),
    'b':np.random.randint(30,MAX_VALUE,OBSERVATIONS)
})
_['res'] = _.apply(lambda x: range(x['a'],x['b']),axis=1)

res1 = _.copy()

start = time.time()
for i in range(MAX_VALUE):
    res1[f'{i}'] = res1['res'].apply(lambda x: 1 if i in x else 0)
print(f'original: {time.time() - start}')

start = time.time()
z = np.zeros((len(_), MAX_VALUE), dtype=np.int64)
for i,r in enumerate(_.res):
    z[i,range(r.start,r.stop)]=1
res2 = pd.concat([_, pd.DataFrame(z)], axis=1)
res2.columns = list(map(str, res2.columns))
print(f'new     : {time.time() - start}')

assert res1.equals(res2)
```

Output:

```
original: 23.649751663208008
new     : 4.586429595947266
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you!